Sound really quiet/silent in voice recording
I'm creating my social media portfolio website with Vue.js and currently trying to implement the html/javascript version of the Media Capture and Streams API, however the recording is created, but it has no sound. So I didn't found much info about this or why this happening and there's no sound just a very quiet tick at the start sometimes, even the length of the audio seems correct just the sound is missing. I've stuck and have no idea what the problem could be.
I've tried different voice formats like webm, mp3, ogg all the same.
I try to pass it to the player component via URL.createObjectURL, the child receive the object as: blob:http://localhost:5173/2214375f-956b-42cd-a4e2-0f477da0feaf
And I pass it directly into the player source.

This is quite unfortunate. Meanwhile, for us to help you please provide a [repro]. Hard to tell what is not working otherwise.

perhaps your microphone is broken - who knows
